# Curious segfault with discriminated union and optional<>

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, segmentation-fault, copy-constructor

I was wondering what could be causing segfaults in this simple example using std::experimental::optional and a union type. What's curious is that a segfault happens in both clang and gcc, but in two different places.

I'm also baffled at the obscene amount of copying and destructing going on which is seen from the logs below, wonder if there's a better/idiomatic way to avoid so many obviously redundant operations? In cases like this, given that all objects here are passed and accessed by-value, would it help to switch all constructors to take rvalue references and use std::move everywhere?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional
#include "Optional/optional.hpp"

using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::experimental::optional;

struct X {
    int y;

    X(int y) : y(y) { cout << "X::X(int)\n"; }
    X(const X& x) : y(x.y) { cout << "X::X(const X&)\n"; }
    ~X() noexcept { cout << "X::~X()\n"; }
};

struct A {
    vector<X> x;

    A(const vector<X>& x) : x(x) { cout << "A::A(const vector<X>&)\n"; }
    A(const A& a) : x(a.x) { cout << "A::A(const A&)\n"; }
    ~A() noexcept { cout << "A::~A()\n"; }

    static optional<A> get() {
        cout << "A::get()\n";
        return A({ X(1), X(2) });
    }
};

struct M {
    union { A a; };

    M(A a) : a(a) {cout << "M::M(A)\n";}
    M(const M &m) { a = m.a; }

    ~M() noexcept {
        cout << "M::~M()\n";
        (&a)->A::~A();
    }

    static optional<M> get() {
        cout << "M::get()\n";
        auto a = A::get();
        return M(*a);
    }
};

struct P {
    vector<M> m;

    P(const vector<M>& m) : m(m) { cout << "P::P(const vector<M>&)\n"; }
    P(const P& p) : m(p.m) { cout << "P::P(const P&)\n"; }

    static optional<P> get() {
        cout << "P::get()\n";
        auto m1 = M::get();
        auto m2 = M::get();
        vector<M> m;
        cout << "push message 1\n";
        m.push_back(*m1);
        cout << "push message 2\n";
        m.push_back(*m2);
        return P(m);
    }
};

int main() {
    auto p = P::get();
    cout << (*p).m[1].a.x[0].y << "\n";
}
```

GCC fails like this:

```
P::get()
M::get()
A::get()
X::X(int)
X::X(int)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
A::A(const vector<X>&)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
A::A(const A&)
A::~A()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
A::A(const A&)
M::M(A)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
A::A(const A&)
'./a.out' terminated by signal SIGBUS (Misaligned address error)

#0  0x0000000100003c59 in X* std::__copy_move<false, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m<X const*, X*>(X const*, X const*, X*) ()
#1  0x000000010000364e in X* std::__copy_move_a<false, X const*, X*>(X const*, X const*, X*) ()
#2  0x0000000100002f3c in __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X*, std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > > std::__copy_move_a2<false, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X const*, std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X*, std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X const*, std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X const*, std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X*, std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > >) ()
#3  0x00000001000025f8 in __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X*, std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > > std::copy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X const*, std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X*, std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X const*, std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X const*, std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X*, std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > >) ()
#4  0x0000000100001d19 in std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> >::operator=(std::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > const&) ()
#5  0x00000001000012ad in A::operator=(A const&) ()
#6  0x00000001000012d7 in M::M(M const&) ()
#7  0x0000000100001356 in std::experimental::storage_t<M>::storage_t<M>(M&&) ()
#8  0x0000000100001393 in std::experimental::optional_base<M>::optional_base(M&&) ()
#9  0x00000001000013c4 in std::experimental::optional<M>::optional(M&&) ()
#10 0x0000000100001456 in M::get() ()
#11 0x00000001000016a8 in P::get() ()
#12 0x0000000100000db1 in main ()
```

whereas clang sometimes doesn't crash and sometimes does like so:

```
P::get()
M::get()
A::get()
X::X(int)
X::X(int)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
A::A(const vector<X>&)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
A::A(const A&)
A::~A()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
A::A(const A&)
M::M(A)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
A::A(const A&)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
M::~M()
A::~A()
X::~X()
X::~X()
A::~A()
X::~X()
X::~X()
A::~A()
X::~X()
X::~X()
M::get()
A::get()
X::X(int)
X::X(int)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
A::A(const vector<X>&)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
A::A(const A&)
A::~A()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
A::A(const A&)
M::M(A)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
A::A(const A&)
X::X(const X&)
X::X(const X&)
M::~M()
A::~A()
X::~X()
X::~X()
A::~A()
X::~X()
X::~X()
A::~A()
X::~X()
X::~X()
push message 1
'./a.out' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Comment: giving `A` a move constructor, and using `a(std::move(a))` instead of `a(a)` would remove a lot of those copies

Comment: logging `X`'s copy and move constructors would help to see if there is something going wrong with the union

Comment: @M.M Yes, thanks for pointing out, I've shortened all variable names so it's easier to read. I've updated the post.

Comment: @M.M Good point about the placement new, hmm however adding `new(&this->a) A(a)` to `M::M(A)` constructor doesn't seem to change anything, it still segfaults at the same spot.

Comment: Why is it curious that the segfaults happen in different places? It's usually caused by undefined behavior, and the actual effects are very dependent on how the compiler generates code.

Comment: Have you tried using `valgrind` to help debug this?

Comment: is `Optional/optional.hpp` actually the right header? can you use `<experimental/optional>` instead?

Comment: @M.M not on gcc <= 4.8... (testing this out on gcc 5 right now but it has to be usable on 4.8). It's the same author and pretty much the same implementation though as in both boost and std -- https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional

Comment: \*ahem\* "Experimental"? ;)

Comment: Regarding the amount of copies - yes, `std::vector` can function better when the underlying type provides a `noexcept` move constructor.  That means when it needs to reallocate its buffer, it can move elements afterwards instead of needing to copy them to provide its strong exception safety guarantees.

Answer (score 6):

You are not constructing the `A` in the `M const&` ctor case, you are just assigning to it when it is uninitialized.

Unions do not construct their contents.

This has nothing to do with optional.

Comment: So the solution would be to use placement new in both `M(const M&)` and `M(A)`? As in, `new(&this->a) A(m.a)` in the copy constructor and `new(&this->a) A(a)` in the normal ctor?

Comment: @aldanor: I'm no unions expert, but presumably `M(const M& m) : a(m.a) {}`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks! See my comment below though -- since `M` is a union type, this has to be done in the copy constructor body unfortunately

Comment: @aldanor: I don't follow.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I meant, your suggestion would work in this (simplified) example, but if the union contained more than one element, only one of them would be initialised (and hence would need to be copied) at a time. This would require additional logic, like a switch statement checking on the tag of the discriminated union, and so the copying would have to be done in the constructor body as opposed to the initialiser list.

Comment: @ald yes, a full on discriminating union requires lots of manual construction (placement new), destruction, care with exception safety, etc.  Look at discussions of `std::experimantal::variant` and sample implementations of it would be my advice.  C++11 permits non-pod types in unions, but that does not make it *easy*.

Comment: Yeah see this is why I don't use unions. `boost::variant` ftw.

Answer (score 4):

The problem (if I'm not wrong) isn't caused by `std::experimental::optional`; it's caused by `union { A a; }` in `struct M` and it's use in `M` copy constructor.

`union { A a; }` is a C++11 union with a non trivial (with non trivial constructor). So, if I remember well, the constructor (and destructor, etc.) is deleted.

We can observe that the copy constructor of `M`

```
M(const M &m) { a = m.a; }
```

is without initializer list; so the `a` element in the union is uninitialized. When is executed the assignments

```
a = m.a;
```

the `a` on the left of the equal sign is uninitialized and (even: if I'm not wrong) the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Solution (I hope):

1) add a default constructor in `A`

```
A() {};
```

2) and initialize `a` in initialization list in copy constructor

```
M(const M &m) : a() { a = m.a; }
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Better solution (thanks Lightness Races in Orbit): inizialize in initialization list with copy constructor of `A`

```
M(const M &m) : a(m.a) { }
```

Comment: Why initialise only to re-assign? Why not `M(const M& m) : a(m.a) {};`? BTW you missed out a colon.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: D'ho! your right: simpler `M(const M &m) : a(m.a) {}`; thanks

Comment: But since `M` is a union type, `a(m.a)` style of initialisation wouldn't really work though. If there was another union field, say, `B b`, you would have to have a switch statement in copy constructor body, how would you do it? What if moreover `A` and `B` don't have default constructors?

Comment: @aldanor - it obvious that your code work only with a single member for the union; another critical point is the `M` destructor: you must know if the union carry an `A` or a `B` to call the right destructor. I suppose that, to support the `M` copy constructor, you should create a constructor for the union. But it's a total different problem. If you play with experimental... you could try a `std::experimental::any` instead of the `union`; or wait the `std::variant` (C++17?)

Comment: @max66 it's not possible to write constructors etc. for anonymous union, the logic has to be in M's constructor etc.

Comment: @ M.M - I didn't know (I don't know unions very well: I only make the possible to avoid them) but I wondered just how to invoke the constructor, in the absence of a name for the union. I think it's another good reason to avoid unions.